# File ownership not changing in bash script

Tags: bash

Im trying to run this script which basically copies an uploaded file to another directory - when I run it, the file gets copied ok but the ownership of the file does not get changed to sales1upload.dba as I expected while it produces the following error on output:

chown: cannot access `test1.txt': No such file or directory

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR="/home/sales1upload/upload"
NEW_BASE_DIR="/bbc/prod/today"
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")


for file in $(ls ${BASE_DIR});
 do

filename=${file}
new_filename=$filename.$current_time

#set user permissions as desired
chown sales1upload.dba "$filename"





cp -prf ${BASE_DIR}/${filename} ${NEW_BASE_DIR}/"moved_files"/$new_filename
cp -prf ${BASE_DIR}/${filename} ${NEW_BASE_DIR}
rm  ${BASE_DIR}/${filename}


done
```

Where am I going wrong with the file ownership in the script?

Comment: That's a [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls).  You want simply `for file in ${BASE_DIR}/*`.  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking `ls` to return a list of files in a directory, but they exist relative to that directory, not relative to the current directory.

As pointed out in comments, you should not be using `ls` for this at all.  Fixing the `ls` to a simple wildcard will also incidentally solve your problem, but now you need to refactor the body of the loop to cope with a full path instead of just a plain file name. (You were already doing the opposite in a couple of places, so this should have been a simple bug to troubleshoot yourself.)

```
for file in "$BASE_DIR"/*; do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    new_filename=$filename.$current_time

    chown sales1upload.dba "$file" 

    cp -prf "$file" "$NEW_BASE_DIR/moved_files/$new_filename"
    cp -prf "$file" "$NEW_BASE_DIR"
    rm  "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

My quick guess: You're not running this in your Base directory, thus you cannot reference the file without specifying the base in the `chmod` argument. Change to:

```
chown sales1upload.dba "${BASE_DIR}/${filename}"
```

I'd like to add that though mine is the straightforward solution to your issue, getting rid of that `ls` as the other answers suggest is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Find files with `find` and not with `ls`. If you use `find`, you have the correct path. In your example you iterate over the relative path and not the absolute path.